# For pen testing why would the client need to sign a NDA?

Tags: penetration-test, legal

I'm starting the process of doing some pen testing and other security related things as a contractor. Specifically regarding pen testing. I have been Googling around to put together some docs for the client to sign authorizing me to do a test. I have an authorization form and I am assuming the client will likely have me sign a NDA to protest their private data. However according one of the answers [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/wjuop/standard_pentesting_contract/) by `ubercl0ud` we should have the client sign a NDA as well. I've been trying to figure out why. I know why the client would want me to sign a NDA. To protect their private data. But what would I need the client to sign a NDA for?

Comment: ubercl0ud there seems to be referring as the NDA to the whole of the documents signed between you and them, so it would contain both your authorization and their confidentiality. Not specifically that you needed an NDA from them.

Comment: Hmm interesting that would make a little more sense then.